# Working with shared_ptr returned from another concrete class

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I need to have access to an object which is implemented in a different concrete class. So I decided to use `std::shared_ptr`. I would like to know whether usage of `std::shared_ptr` is appropriate here, if not please suggest whether I should go with `std::weak_ptr`. So far I have been using raw pointers but now I decided to use smart pointers in my project, But I'm unable to decide which one should I use here. The following code snippet is analogous to what I'm trying to do in my project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class data
{
    public:
    data()
    {
        std::cout<<"\n data constructor Called"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~data()
    {
       std::cout<<"\n data destructor Called"<<std::endl;
    }   
    int GetData()
    {
        return val;
    }
    void SetData(int & val)
    {
        this->val = val;
    }
    private:
    int val;
  };

  class sample
  {
     public:
     sample();
     ~sample();
     void GetShared(std::shared_ptr<data> & arg);
     std::shared_ptr<data> sPtr;
  };

  sample::sample()
  {
     sPtr = std::make_shared<data>();
  }

  sample::~sample()
  {
  }

  void sample::GetShared(std::shared_ptr<data> & arg)
  {
     arg = sPtr;
  }

  int main()
  {
      int val = 40;
      sample obj;
      {
          std::shared_ptr<data> temp1;
          obj.GetShared(temp1);
          temp1->SetData(val);
          std::cout<<"\n Data : "<<temp1->GetData()<<std::endl;
      } // Just to understand whether pointer gets deleted if temp1 goes out of scope.

      {
          std::shared_ptr<data> temp2;
          obj.GetShared(temp2);
          val = 20;
          temp2->SetData(val);
          std::cout<<"\n Data : "<<temp2->GetData()<<std::endl;     
      }

      return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between shared_ptr and weak_ptr is that weak_ptr does not increase the ref count on the object and does prevent the object from being deleted.

This has its pros and cons, if you perform async operations after you obtain the pointer and are unsure whether the object that provided the data has been destroyed then you can use weak_ptr and check if you still have access to the object.

If not then keep it simple and use shared_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

You would use `shared_pointer` to share ownership of some resource, when you don't have a clear owner of that resource.

Here it would be useful if you don't know if `obj` goes out of scope before `temp1` and `temp2` is done with the `data`. However, in this example it is clear that `obj` and the `data` object it holds *will* outlive the user. In that case you could just as well return a normal pointer, or perhaps a reference to the data.

Using  a `shared_pointer` (or a `weak_pointer`) doesn't buy you anything, except added complexity.

Comment: Pretty clear but (in the case of returning normal pointer or reference)what if the user is attempted to delete the pointer which is returned by the method `obj.GetShared(temp1);`. Applying `delete` on the returned `std::shared_ptr` throws compilation error. Am I missing something here and is it still recommended to use normal pointer?.

Comment: @Galik Then how would you return an array correctly in pre-C++11? I have seen a pointer being used for this and similar use cases where the "user" must delete the data.

Comment: @SimonKraemer In pre-c++11 (and post) you would ideally return an array in a `std::vector`. Beyond that it would depend on the wider context - who retains *ownership*.

Comment: @Panch - A persistent user could do `delete temp1.get()` on the `shared_pointer` and destroy that too. You can't protect them from everything.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
  sample obj;
  {
      std::shared_ptr<data> temp1;
      obj.GetShared(temp1);
      temp1->SetData(val);
      std::cout<<"\n Data : "<<temp1->GetData()<<std::endl;
  } // Just to understand whether pointer gets deleted if temp1 goes out of scope.
```

The data will not get deleted, because it is pointing to something that is held by `obj`, which is still alive.

---

I think the answer should depend on whether a `data` object can live after its corresponding  `sample` object died:

- If yes, then it should return a `std::shared_ptr`.
- If not, then it should return a `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Here the `data` object will be destroyed if the `sample` object which contains the `data` is destroyed. Also it is assumed that the `sample` object is lived until the exe is run to finish its activity. So I think that the `std::shared_ptr` is the right choice for me.

Comment: Thanks, @henrikgiesel - appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions you need to ask yourself.

**1)** Will the *calling object* that gets the pointer from `sample` outlive the `sample` object?

If **not** then `sample` should use a `std::unique_ptr` and return a *raw pointer* or a *reference*.

**2)** If the *calling object* does outlive the `sample` object, does it mind if the `data` object gets destroyed before it does?

If **not** then return a `std::weak_ptr` that can be used to test if the `data` object is still alive before using it.

Otherwise return a `std::shared_ptr` to **guarantee** the `data` object lives as long as the *calling object*.

**Summary:**

If the *calling object* will not outlive the `sample` object:

```
class sample
{
    std::unique_ptr<data> ptr; // UNIQUE (not shared)

    public:

    data* GetData() { return ptr.get(); }
};
```

If the *calling object* may outlive the `sample` object but doesn't care if the `data` object lives as long as it does:

```
class sample
{
    std::shared_ptr<data> ptr;

    public:

    std::weak_ptr<data> GetData() { return ptr; }
};
```

If the *calling object* may outlive the `sample` object and needs to `data` object to keep living too:

```
class sample
{
    std::shared_ptr<data> ptr;

    public:

    std::shared_ptr<data> GetData() { return ptr; }
};
```

Comment: The answer is well explained and it gives me a clear picture on how to use C++11 smart pointers. The help is much appreciated.